# Triggering countdown timer remotely

Tags: javascript

I've built a timer in HTML and JavaScript. I want to be able to send a link to a client to a web page with the timer and then be able to start it remotely. How would I go about this?;

Comment: please add code which you have tried

Comment: You need to deploy your timer onto a web server which is accessible from the Internet. Then, you need to store the state of the timer on that web server e.g. in a database or a file (when it started, if it is running etc.). For that you will need a server side programming language (PHP, Java, Python, Node.js, etc.). Then, you probably want some form of authentication. This also needs to be done with the server side programming language (e.g. checking against a list of users with a password).

Comment: Thank you, I looked into Node and its seems thats a good direction to go on.

Comment: If you go for Node.js, you might want to look at Socket.io which makes it very easy to have Websockets. Websockets allow for a remote update of a website.

Comment: Thank you, I shall look into that as well.